# Howto zoom in/out in WinRT Image Control

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a WinRT Metro application where i show an image. 
I now like to zoom in/out with a pinch gesture. Is there an easy way to activate this on the image control, or do i have to implement the whole gesture/pinch logic myself?

Answer (score 6):

I found a better solution.

Just use a ScrollViewer control, this will to the whole zoom for you:

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ImageScrollViewer"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinZoomFactor="0.5" >
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="SmugImage"   Source="http://www.website.com/image.png"  Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Make sure to set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Visible, otherwise the image will be left aligned when you start zooming.

Answer (score 2):

According to a Windows Metro Forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/fd033b83-6557-498f-b532-59fc41210705) there isn't a built in handler for what u want to do, but they do link off to sample code for what i believe you are trying to achieve [on this site](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/01/17/Building-A-Multi-Touch-Photo-Viewer-Control.aspx)

Comment: I found this sample already, but it's for the phone. I thought before trying to implement this one, i should look for a native WinRT control/sample.